# Network request failed. On android

Tags: asp.net, react-native

I am working on react-native and asp.net core api. My asp.net api runs on https://localhost:44388/ so, I put this origin as url in `fetch()`. That throws above error. I even get suggestion to put my Laptop's IP address instead of localhost. And when I checked on my android device, that does not work.

```
getProducts(){
console.log("Hello");
fetch("https://<MY_IP_ADDR>:44388/api/product/getproducts/", {
            method: 'get',
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Mehods': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': '*',
            }
        })
            .then(data => {
                if (!data.ok) {
                    console.log("Inside product fetch: Error fetching")
                } else {
                    return data.json()
                }
            }).then(data => this.setState({ products: data }))
            .then(data=>console.log(data))
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
            })
}
```

```
 <View>
                <Text>Products</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.getProducts()}>
                    <Text>getProducts</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
```

When I press getProducts button, It just enters the method `getProducts()` and prints "Hello" on console, but the flow don't enter `fetch()` method. My metro bundler is running on port 8081. I was adviced to change that port. So, I tried to change by command `react-native start --port 44388` but that throws an error at event.js:174. And there is no issue with cors because I enabled cors on my backend part which works totally fine with react app.
How will I be able to call localhost api in my android device?

Comment: try `fetch("http://<MY_IP_ADDR>:44388/api/product/getproducts/"`

Comment: Nope this doesn't work

Comment: debug js remotely and check in browsers whether the network request is getting parsed.

Comment: No it throws an error: TypeError: Network request failed Also I have been suggested to use https://ngrok.com to make local api availble to use as real ones. But I dont know how to use that.